# xUnit tests do not appear on tfs

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, xunit

locally tests and works. but it does not see the tfs te on the server and it does not work.
I can not see the xUnit test in Tfs and I can not work with it.
TFS version 2017

--- [Solition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575773/running-xunit-tests-on-tfs-build-pipeline/47590938#47590938)----

Comment: Do you have the runner nuget added to the solution?

Comment: Yes I did. This time he can not discovered. I guess I need a custom build configuration

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about on premise TFS, but VSTS picks up automatically the runners, which are in the Nuget folder.

My second idea is about the .NET version. `xunit.extensibility.core` has a dependency on .NET 4.5.2, so if you're on a lower version, it could be an issue.

Comment: which unfortunately did not provide a complete solution

Comment: What's the type of your project, dotnet or dotnet core or something?

Comment: Moreover, could you share related detail  error log?

Comment: yes i am using .netcore and  [my project log](https://ybin.me/p/e2167b0a982a3c95#u2WnZLJSCQqHOlFBe1uEovQGJ0mKL2W0zWRgfXuSqrY=)

Comment: @ahmeturganci Try to use .net core command line instead of VSTEST task to run the test, details please see my answer below.  Besides, if you need to notify somebody you could use `@` symbol.

Comment: Thank you. I will try @PatrickLu-MSFT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For normal project, you could directly use Visual Studio Test task in the build pipeline.

You could try to  explicitly specific the path to the  xunit runner. Such as

`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\packages\xunit.runner.visualstudio.2.2.0\build\_common)`

And Szeki's comment is right, xUnit test runner can only be run in an assembly targeting .NET 4.5.2 or above, otherwise it cannot be loaded (and thus the tests will not be found). Take a look at this question: [Running xunit.net tests in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927263/running-xunit-net-tests-in-vsts)

If you are working with  .net core project, you should use .net core command line to run the test instead of VStest. Details info please refer below blog:

- [Publish Core XUnit Test Results in VSTS](http://tech.trailmax.info/2017/06/publish-core-xunit-test-results-in-vsts/)
- [VSTS Configuration to run xUnit tests for x64 platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287353/vsts-configuration-to-run-xunit-tests-for-x64-platform)